# How can i use node js backend with Nextjs App router version

Tags: next.js

Hi i want use node js backend with Nextjs App router version. I found a lot way but all of them for pages router. Offical docs give method but all of them pages router version . I have api folder and it works http://localhost:8800 but I cant forward link to api. I tried with Nextjs fetch and axios. Any suggestions?

How can I forward backend to next js with axios or anything